# Why do strtod() and strtof() of the Newlib C Standard Library implementation uses dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, embedded, newlib, c-standard-library, strtod

Newlib is a C standard library implementation (largely inspired by BSD libc) intended for use on embedded systems.

Apparently, the string to floating point conversion functions (`strtod`, `strtof`) use dynamic memory allocation by calling a function called `Balloc`, which calls `_calloc_r` which calls `_malloc_r`.

Why?

I tried to look at the source code available [online](http://git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git), but I couldn't make sense of it.

I found the call for the `_Balloc` in the disassembly and tried many different inputs (strings) to try and trigger it getting called, but I didn't managed to get it called. (I can't trace the program in the C source code, as the library is precompiled (shared library) with heavy optimizations.)

I need to use a library that is full with calls to `strtod` and the rest, so I can't easily eliminate these functions.
I don't have a heap on the microcontroller, I don't want to have a heap on the microcontroller, and I don't even have the `_sbrk` function (which would ultimately be responsible for allocating the memory from the heap) implemented for me...

I now have only a stub for the `_sbrk` which just triggers a hard fault if it gets called, so that the linker doesn't fail. But this is obviously not very good.

So I would like to know, why and when (what kind of input) will Balloc be called.
Maybe I can prove that that type of input is impossible in my case so the stub would be a sanctionable hack.

Here is the strtod.c: https://www.codepile.net/pile/JZVLj6yQ

Edit:

_strtod_l() (this is what gets wrapped by strtod):

```
double
_strtod_l (struct _reent *ptr, const char *__restrict s00, char **__restrict se,
       locale_t loc)
{
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
    int scale;
#endif
    int bb2, bb5, bbe, bd2, bd5, bbbits, bs2, c, decpt, dsign,
         e, e1, esign, i, j, k, nd, nd0, nf, nz, nz0, sign;
    const char *s, *s0, *s1;
    double aadj, adj;
    U aadj1, rv, rv0;
    Long L;
    __ULong y, z;
    _Bigint *bb = NULL, *bb1, *bd = NULL, *bd0, *bs = NULL, *delta = NULL;
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
    __ULong Lsb, Lsb1;
#endif
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
    int inexact, oldinexact;
#endif
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
    int rounding;
#endif
    const char *decimal_point = __get_numeric_locale(loc)->decimal_point;
    int dec_len = strlen (decimal_point);

    delta = bs = bd = NULL;
    sign = nz0 = nz = decpt = 0;
    dval(rv) = 0.;
    for(s = s00;;s++) switch(*s) {
        case '-':
            sign = 1;
            /* no break */
        case '+':
            if (*++s)
                goto break2;
            /* no break */
        case 0:
            goto ret0;
        case '\t':
        case '\n':
        case '\v':
        case '\f':
        case '\r':
        case ' ':
            continue;
        default:
            goto break2;
        }
 break2:
    if (*s == '0') {
#ifndef NO_HEX_FP
        {
        static const FPI fpi = { 53, 1-1023-53+1, 2046-1023-53+1, 1, SI };
        Long exp;
        __ULong bits[2];
        switch(s[1]) {
          case 'x':
          case 'X':
            /* If the number is not hex, then the parse of
                           0 is still valid.  */
            s00 = s + 1;
            {
#if defined(FE_DOWNWARD) && defined(FE_TONEAREST) && defined(FE_TOWARDZERO) && defined(FE_UPWARD)
            FPI fpi1 = fpi;
            switch(fegetround()) {
              case FE_TOWARDZERO:   fpi1.rounding = 0; break;
              case FE_UPWARD:   fpi1.rounding = 2; break;
              case FE_DOWNWARD: fpi1.rounding = 3;
              }
#else
#define fpi1 fpi
#endif
            switch((i = gethex(ptr, &s, &fpi1, &exp, &bb, sign, loc)) & STRTOG_Retmask) {
              case STRTOG_NoNumber:
                s = s00;
                sign = 0;
                /* FALLTHROUGH */
              case STRTOG_Zero:
                break;
              default:
                if (bb) {
                    copybits(bits, fpi.nbits, bb);
                    Bfree(ptr,bb);
                    }
                ULtod(rv.i, bits, exp, i);
              }}
            goto ret;
          }
        }
#endif
        nz0 = 1;
        while(*++s == '0') ;
        if (!*s)
            goto ret;
        }
    s0 = s;
    y = z = 0;
    for(nd = nf = 0; (c = *s) >= '0' && c <= '9'; nd++, s++)
        if (nd < 9)
            y = 10*y + c - '0';
        else
            z = 10*z + c - '0';
    nd0 = nd;
    if (strncmp (s, decimal_point, dec_len) == 0)
        {
        decpt = 1;
        c = *(s += dec_len);
        if (!nd) {
            for(; c == '0'; c = *++s)
                nz++;
            if (c > '0' && c <= '9') {
                s0 = s;
                nf += nz;
                nz = 0;
                goto have_dig;
                }
            goto dig_done;
            }
        for(; c >= '0' && c <= '9'; c = *++s) {
 have_dig:
            nz++;
            if (c -= '0') {
                nf += nz;
                for(i = 1; i < nz; i++)
                    if (nd++ < 9)
                        y *= 10;
                    else if (nd <= DBL_DIG + 1)
                        z *= 10;
                if (nd++ < 9)
                    y = 10*y + c;
                else if (nd <= DBL_DIG + 1)
                    z = 10*z + c;
                nz = 0;
                }
            }
        }
 dig_done:
    e = 0;
    if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
        if (!nd && !nz && !nz0) {
            goto ret0;
            }
        s00 = s;
        esign = 0;
        switch(c = *++s) {
            case '-':
                esign = 1;
            case '+':
                c = *++s;
            }
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            while(c == '0')
                c = *++s;
            if (c > '0' && c <= '9') {
                L = c - '0';
                s1 = s;
                while((c = *++s) >= '0' && c <= '9')
                    L = 10*L + c - '0';
                if (s - s1 > 8 || L > 19999)
                    /* Avoid confusion from exponents
                     * so large that e might overflow.
                     */
                    e = 19999; /* safe for 16 bit ints */
                else
                    e = (int)L;
                if (esign)
                    e = -e;
                }
            else
                e = 0;
            }
        else
            s = s00;
        }
    if (!nd) {
        if (!nz && !nz0) {
#ifdef INFNAN_CHECK
            /* Check for Nan and Infinity */
            __ULong bits[2];
            static const FPI fpinan =   /* only 52 explicit bits */
                { 52, 1-1023-53+1, 2046-1023-53+1, 1, SI };
            if (!decpt)
             switch(c) {
              case 'i':
              case 'I':
                if (match(&s,"nf")) {
                    --s;
                    if (!match(&s,"inity"))
                        ++s;
                    dword0(rv) = 0x7ff00000;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword1(rv) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                    goto ret;
                    }
                break;
              case 'n':
              case 'N':
                if (match(&s, "an")) {
#ifndef No_Hex_NaN
                    if (*s == '(' /*)*/
                     && hexnan(&s, &fpinan, bits)
                            == STRTOG_NaNbits) {
                        dword0(rv) = 0x7ff00000 | bits[1];
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                        dword1(rv) = bits[0];
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                        }
                    else {
#endif
                        dval(rv) = nan ("");
#ifndef No_Hex_NaN
                        }
#endif
                    goto ret;
                    }
              }
#endif /* INFNAN_CHECK */
 ret0:
            s = s00;
            sign = 0;
            }
        goto ret;
        }
    e1 = e -= nf;

    /* Now we have nd0 digits, starting at s0, followed by a
     * decimal point, followed by nd-nd0 digits.  The number we're
     * after is the integer represented by those digits times
     * 10**e */

    if (!nd0)
        nd0 = nd;
    k = nd < DBL_DIG + 1 ? nd : DBL_DIG + 1;
    dval(rv) = y;
    if (k > 9) {
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
        if (k > DBL_DIG)
            oldinexact = get_inexact();
#endif
        dval(rv) = tens[k - 9] * dval(rv) + z;
        }
    bd0 = 0;
    if (nd <= DBL_DIG
#ifndef RND_PRODQUOT
#ifndef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
        && Flt_Rounds == 1
#endif
#endif
            ) {
        if (!e)
            goto ret;
        if (e > 0) {
            if (e <= Ten_pmax) {
#ifdef VAX
                goto vax_ovfl_check;
#else
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
                /* round correctly FLT_ROUNDS = 2 or 3 */
                if (sign) {
                    dval(rv) = -dval(rv);
                    sign = 0;
                    }
#endif
                /* rv = */ rounded_product(dval(rv), tens[e]);
                goto ret;
#endif
                }
            i = DBL_DIG - nd;
            if (e <= Ten_pmax + i) {
                /* A fancier test would sometimes let us do
                 * this for larger i values.
                 */
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
                /* round correctly FLT_ROUNDS = 2 or 3 */
                if (sign) {
                    dval(rv) = -dval(rv);
                    sign = 0;
                    }
#endif
                e -= i;
                dval(rv) *= tens[i];
#ifdef VAX
                /* VAX exponent range is so narrow we must
                 * worry about overflow here...
                 */
 vax_ovfl_check:
                dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
                /* rv = */ rounded_product(dval(rv), tens[e]);
                if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)
                 > Exp_msk1*(DBL_MAX_EXP+Bias-1-P))
                    goto ovfl;
                dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
#else
                /* rv = */ rounded_product(dval(rv), tens[e]);
#endif
                goto ret;
                }
            }
#ifndef Inaccurate_Divide
        else if (e >= -Ten_pmax) {
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
            /* round correctly FLT_ROUNDS = 2 or 3 */
            if (sign) {
                dval(rv) = -dval(rv);
                sign = 0;
                }
#endif
            /* rv = */ rounded_quotient(dval(rv), tens[-e]);
            goto ret;
            }
#endif
        }
    e1 += nd - k;

#ifdef IEEE_Arith
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
    inexact = 1;
    if (k <= DBL_DIG)
        oldinexact = get_inexact();
#endif
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
    scale = 0;
#endif
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
    if ((rounding = Flt_Rounds) >= 2) {
        if (sign)
            rounding = rounding == 2 ? 0 : 2;
        else
            if (rounding != 2)
                rounding = 0;
        }
#endif
#endif /*IEEE_Arith*/

    /* Get starting approximation = rv * 10**e1 */

    if (e1 > 0) {
        if ( (i = e1 & 15) !=0)
            dval(rv) *= tens[i];
        if (e1 &= ~15) {
            if (e1 > DBL_MAX_10_EXP) {
 ovfl:
#ifndef NO_ERRNO
                ptr->_errno = ERANGE;
#endif
                /* Can't trust HUGE_VAL */
#ifdef IEEE_Arith
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
                switch(rounding) {
                  case 0: /* toward 0 */
                  case 3: /* toward -infinity */
                    dword0(rv) = Big0;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword1(rv) = Big1;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                    break;
                  default:
                    dword0(rv) = Exp_mask;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword1(rv) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                  }
#else /*Honor_FLT_ROUNDS*/
                dword0(rv) = Exp_mask;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword1(rv) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
#endif /*Honor_FLT_ROUNDS*/
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
                /* set overflow bit */
                dval(rv0) = 1e300;
                dval(rv0) *= dval(rv0);
#endif
#else /*IEEE_Arith*/
                dword0(rv) = Big0;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword1(rv) = Big1;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
#endif /*IEEE_Arith*/
                if (bd0)
                    goto retfree;
                goto ret;
                }
            e1 >>= 4;
            for(j = 0; e1 > 1; j++, e1 >>= 1)
                if (e1 & 1)
                    dval(rv) *= bigtens[j];
        /* The last multiplication could overflow. */
            dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
            dval(rv) *= bigtens[j];
            if ((z = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)
             > Exp_msk1*(DBL_MAX_EXP+Bias-P))
                goto ovfl;
            if (z > Exp_msk1*(DBL_MAX_EXP+Bias-1-P)) {
                /* set to largest number */
                /* (Can't trust DBL_MAX) */
                dword0(rv) = Big0;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword1(rv) = Big1;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                }
            else
                dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
            }
        }
    else if (e1 < 0) {
        e1 = -e1;
        if ( (i = e1 & 15) !=0)
            dval(rv) /= tens[i];
        if (e1 >>= 4) {
            if (e1 >= 1 << n_bigtens)
                goto undfl;
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            if (e1 & Scale_Bit)
                scale = 2*P;
            for(j = 0; e1 > 0; j++, e1 >>= 1)
                if (e1 & 1)
                    dval(rv) *= tinytens[j];
            if (scale && (j = 2*P + 1 - ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)
                        >> Exp_shift)) > 0) {
                /* scaled rv is denormal; zap j low bits */
                if (j >= 32) {
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword1(rv) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                    if (j >= 53)
                     dword0(rv) = (P+2)*Exp_msk1;
                    else
                     dword0(rv) &= 0xffffffff << (j-32);
                    }
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                else
                    dword1(rv) &= 0xffffffff << j;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                }
#else
            for(j = 0; e1 > 1; j++, e1 >>= 1)
                if (e1 & 1)
                    dval(rv) *= tinytens[j];
            /* The last multiplication could underflow. */
            dval(rv0) = dval(rv);
            dval(rv) *= tinytens[j];
            if (!dval(rv)) {
                dval(rv) = 2.*dval(rv0);
                dval(rv) *= tinytens[j];
#endif
                if (!dval(rv)) {
 undfl:
                    dval(rv) = 0.;
#ifndef NO_ERRNO
                    ptr->_errno = ERANGE;
#endif
                    if (bd0)
                        goto retfree;
                    goto ret;
                    }
#ifndef Avoid_Underflow
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword0(rv) = Tiny0;
                dword1(rv) = Tiny1;
#else
                dword0(rv) = Tiny1;
#endif /*_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                /* The refinement below will clean
                 * this approximation up.
                 */
                }
#endif
            }
        }

    /* Now the hard part -- adjusting rv to the correct value.*/

    /* Put digits into bd: true value = bd * 10^e */

    bd0 = s2b(ptr, s0, nd0, nd, y);
    if (bd0 == NULL)
        goto ovfl;

    for(;;) {
        bd = Balloc(ptr,bd0->_k);
        if (bd == NULL)
            goto ovfl;
        Bcopy(bd, bd0);
        bb = d2b(ptr,dval(rv), &bbe, &bbbits);  /* rv = bb * 2^bbe */
        if (bb == NULL)
            goto ovfl;
        bs = i2b(ptr,1);
        if (bs == NULL)
            goto ovfl;

        if (e >= 0) {
            bb2 = bb5 = 0;
            bd2 = bd5 = e;
            }
        else {
            bb2 = bb5 = -e;
            bd2 = bd5 = 0;
            }
        if (bbe >= 0)
            bb2 += bbe;
        else
            bd2 -= bbe;
        bs2 = bb2;
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
        if (rounding != 1)
            bs2++;
#endif
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
        Lsb = LSB;
        Lsb1 = 0;
        j = bbe - scale;
        i = j + bbbits - 1; /* logb(rv) */
        j = P + 1 - bbbits;
        if (i < Emin) { /* denormal */
            i = Emin - i;
            j -= i;
            if (i < 32)
                Lsb <<= i;
            else
                Lsb1 = Lsb << (i-32);
            }
#else /*Avoid_Underflow*/
#ifdef Sudden_Underflow
#ifdef IBM
        j = 1 + 4*P - 3 - bbbits + ((bbe + bbbits - 1) & 3);
#else
        j = P + 1 - bbbits;
#endif
#else /*Sudden_Underflow*/
        j = bbe;
        i = j + bbbits - 1; /* logb(rv) */
        if (i < Emin)   /* denormal */
            j += P - Emin;
        else
            j = P + 1 - bbbits;
#endif /*Sudden_Underflow*/
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
        bb2 += j;
        bd2 += j;
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
        bd2 += scale;
#endif
        i = bb2 < bd2 ? bb2 : bd2;
        if (i > bs2)
            i = bs2;
        if (i > 0) {
            bb2 -= i;
            bd2 -= i;
            bs2 -= i;
            }
        if (bb5 > 0) {
            bs = pow5mult(ptr, bs, bb5);
            if (bs == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            bb1 = mult(ptr, bs, bb);
            if (bb1 == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            Bfree(ptr, bb);
            bb = bb1;
            }
        if (bb2 > 0) {
            bb = lshift(ptr, bb, bb2);
            if (bb == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            }
        if (bd5 > 0) {
            bd = pow5mult(ptr, bd, bd5);
            if (bd == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            }
        if (bd2 > 0) {
            bd = lshift(ptr, bd, bd2);
            if (bd == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            }
        if (bs2 > 0) {
            bs = lshift(ptr, bs, bs2);
            if (bs == NULL)
                goto ovfl;
            }
        delta = diff(ptr, bb, bd);
        if (delta == NULL)
            goto ovfl;
        dsign = delta->_sign;
        delta->_sign = 0;
        i = cmp(delta, bs);
#ifdef Honor_FLT_ROUNDS
        if (rounding != 1) {
            if (i < 0) {
                /* Error is less than an ulp */
                if (!delta->_x[0] && delta->_wds <= 1) {
                    /* exact */
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
                    inexact = 0;
#endif
                    break;
                    }
                if (rounding) {
                    if (dsign) {
                        adj = 1.;
                        goto apply_adj;
                        }
                    }
                else if (!dsign) {
                    adj = -1.;
                    if (!dword1(rv)
                        && !(dword0(rv) & Frac_mask)) {
                        y = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask;
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                        if (!scale || y > 2*P*Exp_msk1)
#else
                        if (y)
#endif
                          {
                          delta = lshift(ptr, delta,Log2P);
                          if (cmp(delta, bs) <= 0)
                            adj = -0.5;
                          }
                        }
 apply_adj:
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                    if (scale && (y = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)
                        <= 2*P*Exp_msk1)
                      dword0(adj) += (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1 - y;
#else
#ifdef Sudden_Underflow
                    if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <=
                            P*Exp_msk1) {
                        dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
                        dval(rv) += adj*ulp(dval(rv));
                        dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
                        }
                    else
#endif /*Sudden_Underflow*/
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
                    dval(rv) += adj*ulp(dval(rv));
                    }
                break;
                }
            adj = ratio(delta, bs);
            if (adj < 1.)
                adj = 1.;
            if (adj <= 0x7ffffffe) {
                /* adj = rounding ? ceil(adj) : floor(adj); */
                y = adj;
                if (y != adj) {
                    if (!((rounding>>1) ^ dsign))
                        y++;
                    adj = y;
                    }
                }
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            if (scale && (y = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= 2*P*Exp_msk1)
                dword0(adj) += (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1 - y;
#else
#ifdef Sudden_Underflow
            if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= P*Exp_msk1) {
                dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
                adj *= ulp(dval(rv));
                if (dsign)
                    dval(rv) += adj;
                else
                    dval(rv) -= adj;
                dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
                goto cont;
                }
#endif /*Sudden_Underflow*/
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
            adj *= ulp(dval(rv));
            if (dsign) {
                if (dword0(rv) == Big0 && dword1(rv) == Big1)
                    goto ovfl;
                dval(rv) += adj;
            else
                dval(rv) -= adj;
            goto cont;
            }
#endif /*Honor_FLT_ROUNDS*/

        if (i < 0) {
            /* Error is less than half an ulp -- check for
             * special case of mantissa a power of two.
             */
            if (dsign || dword1(rv) || dword0(rv) & Bndry_mask
#ifdef IEEE_Arith
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
             || (dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1
#else
             || (dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= Exp_msk1
#endif
#endif
                ) {
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
                if (!delta->x[0] && delta->wds <= 1)
                    inexact = 0;
#endif
                break;
                }
            if (!delta->_x[0] && delta->_wds <= 1) {
                /* exact result */
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
                inexact = 0;
#endif
                break;
                }
            delta = lshift(ptr,delta,Log2P);
            if (cmp(delta, bs) > 0)
                goto drop_down;
            break;
            }
        if (i == 0) {
            /* exactly half-way between */
            if (dsign) {
                if ((dword0(rv) & Bndry_mask1) == Bndry_mask1
                 &&  dword1(rv) == (
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            (scale && (y = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= 2*P*Exp_msk1)
        ? (0xffffffff & (0xffffffff << (2*P+1-(y>>Exp_shift)))) :
#endif
                           0xffffffff)) {
                    /*boundary case -- increment exponent*/
                    if (dword0(rv) == Big0 && dword1(rv) == Big1)
                        goto ovfl;
                    dword0(rv) = (dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)
                        + Exp_msk1
#ifdef IBM
                        | Exp_msk1 >> 4
#endif
                        ;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword1(rv) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                    dsign = 0;
#endif
                    break;
                    }
                }
            else if (!(dword0(rv) & Bndry_mask) && !dword1(rv)) {
 drop_down:
                /* boundary case -- decrement exponent */
#ifdef Sudden_Underflow /*{{*/
                L = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask;
#ifdef IBM
                if (L <  Exp_msk1)
#else
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                if (L <= (scale ? (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1 : Exp_msk1))
#else
                if (L <= Exp_msk1)
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
#endif /*IBM*/
                    goto undfl;
                L -= Exp_msk1;
#else /*Sudden_Underflow}{*/
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                if (scale) {
                    L = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask;
                    if (L <= (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1) {
                        if (L > (P+2)*Exp_msk1)
                            /* round even ==> */
                            /* accept rv */
                            break;
                        /* rv = smallest denormal */
                        goto undfl;
                        }
                    }
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
                L = (dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) - Exp_msk1;
#endif /*Sudden_Underflow}*/
                dword0(rv) = L | Bndry_mask1;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword1(rv) = 0xffffffff;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
#ifdef IBM
                goto cont;
#else
                break;
#endif
                }
#ifndef ROUND_BIASED
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            if (Lsb1) {
                if (!(dword0(rv) & Lsb1))
                    break;
                }
            else if (!(dword1(rv) & Lsb))
                break;
#else
            if (!(dword1(rv) & LSB))
                break;
#endif
#endif
            if (dsign)
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                dval(rv) += sulp(rv, scale);
#else
                dval(rv) += ulp(dval(rv));
#endif
#ifndef ROUND_BIASED
            else {
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
                dval(rv) -= sulp(rv, scale);
#else
                dval(rv) -= ulp(dval(rv));
#endif
#ifndef Sudden_Underflow
                if (!dval(rv))
                    goto undfl;
#endif
                }
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            dsign = 1 - dsign;
#endif
#endif
            break;
            }
        if ((aadj = ratio(delta, bs)) <= 2.) {
            if (dsign)
                aadj = dval(aadj1) = 1.;
            else if (dword1(rv) || dword0(rv) & Bndry_mask) {
#ifndef Sudden_Underflow
                if (dword1(rv) == Tiny1 && !dword0(rv))
                    goto undfl;
#endif
                aadj = 1.;
                dval(aadj1) = -1.;
                }
            else {
                /* special case -- power of FLT_RADIX to be */
                /* rounded down... */

                if (aadj < 2./FLT_RADIX)
                    aadj = 1./FLT_RADIX;
                else
                    aadj *= 0.5;
                dval(aadj1) = -aadj;
                }
            }
        else {
            aadj *= 0.5;
            dval(aadj1) = dsign ? aadj : -aadj;
#ifdef Check_FLT_ROUNDS
            switch(Rounding) {
                case 2: /* towards +infinity */
                    dval(aadj1) -= 0.5;
                    break;
                case 0: /* towards 0 */
                case 3: /* towards -infinity */
                    dval(aadj1) += 0.5;
                }
#else
            if (Flt_Rounds == 0)
                dval(aadj1) += 0.5;
#endif /*Check_FLT_ROUNDS*/
            }
        y = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask;

        /* Check for overflow */

        if (y == Exp_msk1*(DBL_MAX_EXP+Bias-1)) {
            dval(rv0) = dval(rv);
            dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
            adj = dval(aadj1) * ulp(dval(rv));
            dval(rv) += adj;
            if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) >=
                    Exp_msk1*(DBL_MAX_EXP+Bias-P)) {
                if (dword0(rv0) == Big0 && dword1(rv0) == Big1)
                    goto ovfl;
                dword0(rv) = Big0;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                dword1(rv) = Big1;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                goto cont;
                }
            else
                dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
            }
        else {
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
            if (scale && y <= 2*P*Exp_msk1) {
                if (aadj <= 0x7fffffff) {
                    if ((z = aadj) == 0)
                        z = 1;
                    aadj = z;
                    dval(aadj1) = dsign ? aadj : -aadj;
                    }
                dword0(aadj1) += (2*P+1)*Exp_msk1 - y;
                }
            adj = dval(aadj1) * ulp(dval(rv));
            dval(rv) += adj;
#else
#ifdef Sudden_Underflow
            if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= P*Exp_msk1) {
                dval(rv0) = dval(rv);
                dword0(rv) += P*Exp_msk1;
                adj = dval(aadj1) * ulp(dval(rv));
                dval(rv) += adj;
#ifdef IBM
                if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <  P*Exp_msk1)
#else
                if ((dword0(rv) & Exp_mask) <= P*Exp_msk1)
#endif
                    {
                    if (dword0(rv0) == Tiny0
                     && dword1(rv0) == Tiny1)
                        goto undfl;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
                    dword0(rv) = Tiny0;
                    dword1(rv) = Tiny1;
#else
                    dword0(rv) = Tiny1;
#endif /*_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
                    goto cont;
                    }
                else
                    dword0(rv) -= P*Exp_msk1;
                }
            else {
                adj = dval(aadj1) * ulp(dval(rv));
                dval(rv) += adj;
                }
#else /*Sudden_Underflow*/
            /* Compute adj so that the IEEE rounding rules will
             * correctly round rv + adj in some half-way cases.
             * If rv * ulp(rv) is denormalized (i.e.,
             * y <= (P-1)*Exp_msk1), we must adjust aadj to avoid
             * trouble from bits lost to denormalization;
             * example: 1.2e-307 .
             */
            if (y <= (P-1)*Exp_msk1 && aadj > 1.) {
                dval(aadj1) = (double)(int)(aadj + 0.5);
                if (!dsign)
                    dval(aadj1) = -dval(aadj1);
                }
            adj = dval(aadj1) * ulp(dval(rv));
            dval(rv) += adj;
#endif /*Sudden_Underflow*/
#endif /*Avoid_Underflow*/
            }
        z = dword0(rv) & Exp_mask;
#ifndef SET_INEXACT
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
        if (!scale)
#endif
        if (y == z) {
            /* Can we stop now? */
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
            /* If FE_INVALID floating point exceptions are
               enabled, a conversion to a 32 bit value is
               dangerous.  A positive double value can result
               in a negative 32 bit int, thus raising SIGFPE.
               To avoid this, always convert into 64 bit here. */
            __int64_t L = (__int64_t)aadj;
#else
            L = (Long)aadj;
#endif
            aadj -= L;
            /* The tolerances below are conservative. */
            if (dsign || dword1(rv) || dword0(rv) & Bndry_mask) {
                if (aadj < .4999999 || aadj > .5000001)
                    break;
                }
            else if (aadj < .4999999/FLT_RADIX)
                break;
            }
#endif
 cont:
        Bfree(ptr,bb);
        Bfree(ptr,bd);
        Bfree(ptr,bs);
        Bfree(ptr,delta);
        }
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
    if (inexact) {
        if (!oldinexact) {
            dword0(rv0) = Exp_1 + (70 << Exp_shift);
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
            dword1(rv0) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
            dval(rv0) += 1.;
            }
        }
    else if (!oldinexact)
        clear_inexact();
#endif
#ifdef Avoid_Underflow
    if (scale) {
        dword0(rv0) = Exp_1 - 2*P*Exp_msk1;
#ifndef _DOUBLE_IS_32BITS
        dword1(rv0) = 0;
#endif /*!_DOUBLE_IS_32BITS*/
        dval(rv) *= dval(rv0);
#ifndef NO_ERRNO
        /* try to avoid the bug of testing an 8087 register value */
        if (dword0(rv) == 0 && dword1(rv) == 0)
            ptr->_errno = ERANGE;
#endif
        }
#endif /* Avoid_Underflow */
#ifdef SET_INEXACT
    if (inexact && !(dword0(rv) & Exp_mask)) {
        /* set underflow bit */
        dval(rv0) = 1e-300;
        dval(rv0) *= dval(rv0);
        }
#endif
 retfree:
    Bfree(ptr,bb);
    Bfree(ptr,bd);
    Bfree(ptr,bs);
    Bfree(ptr,bd0);
    Bfree(ptr,delta);
 ret:
    if (se)
        *se = (char *)s;
    return sign ? -dval(rv) : dval(rv);
}
```

Comment: for strtod? It's quite long, so I didn't want to copy-paste it; It would be a big wall of code.

Comment: I get lost immediately when strtod calls _strtod_l. (strtod is a wrapper for the latter) The main issue isn't a lack of knowledge of C but a lack of knowledge of how the Standard Library works: _strtod_l (_REENT, s00, se, __get_current_locale ()); I hadn't even know what _REENT was before I researched...

Comment: of course I got further than this, but you get the idea...

Comment: @tadman I added the code for the function that implements strtod()

Comment: It's using a `Bigint` type to do the numeric conversion, which is (a) definitely going to require dynamic memory allocation, (b) overkill in my opinion, and (c) definitely not what you want in a streamlined, embedded application!

Comment: Please correct the [online](http://git//sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git) link in your question which is wrong. And also better post `strtol` which should be much simpler than `strtod`; I'd be curious why they use dynamic memory allocation for `strtol`.

Comment: @SteveSummit This makes a lot of sense. You basically answered my question. So, apparently for `999999999999999` it still doesn't use dynamic memory, for `1000000000000000` though it does. So, if the number of digits are more than 15, it will start using `Bigint` to do the conversion. I guess it stores the the whole number in an `int` and then divides down with the exponent (plus conversion error correcting magic). The built in integer types stop being big enough at some point.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You are right, `strtol` actually doesn't use dynamic memory, only `strtod` and `strtof`. I didn't check the code of those before. I only noticed that I needed to remove them so that the linker doesn't cry over the missing `_sbrk`, but apparently I messed up something because now that I tried again they can stay in the code and not cause the linker to fail... Sorry! I'll edit the question. The link is good though, it it a git repo. You can clone it. I is the only official source, I could find.

Comment: `Why?` Because someone implemented it that way. I do not really understand the question - it's hard to answer design choices. Ask the person that implemented it - what were his design choices and priorities and how did he achieve that. Sorry, converting floating point numbers to a string is _extremely hard_. One could design a conversion without dynamic allocation - surely such conversion will have limits. If you can, print the floating point in hex format, or just as a number. Do you actuallly need precise base-10 floating point strings? Roll your own imprecise function.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is the other way around str to float, and I mostly got the answer for the why in the comments.

Comment: Och right, it's the other way round! Newlib is the "default" nowadays for embedded systems, but it wasn't meant to be used on bare-metal with no dynamic allocation. Check out other C standard libraries. Ex. [dietlibc](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/lib/strtod.c) looks just nice, although it will have conversion errors. And anyway, if you do not have `_sbrk`, implementing one over statically allocated array is just few lines.

Comment: This code is awfully written even as library goo goes. Hello and welcome to the 1980s, we have now have inline functions...

Comment: @Lundin: Remember that some embedded chips have a bad compiler written by the vendor and last updated in 1990.

Comment: @ZanLynx This one is apparently some open source barf originating from Cygwin. Most  of the truly bad code I see nowadays comes from open source projects. Though apparently Red Hat maintain it now, so they should feel ashamed.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do strtod() and strtof() of the Newlib C Standard Library implementation uses dynamic memory allocation?

Leap of faith having not scanned the code:  **Because a quality conversion takes *lots* of space**.

Consider `DBL_MIN` takes [hundreds of digits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) to convert to a string *exactly*. The next largest value also takes a similar amount of digits.  A *string* nearly exactly half-way in between needs to examine these 100s of decimal digits, all the while forming a very long binary form in addition to the exponent it may have to multiply, in order return the *best* `double` answer.  Code is allocating based on its dynamic need.

If one is satisfied with a less-than-optimal conversion,  only a few dozen bytes are needed for conversion to `double`.

Choose your trade-offs: correctness, speed, size.

Comment: This is the other way around, `strtod()` is converting FROM string to double. It looks like it is allocating dynamic memory if it can't fit all the digits in a `long int`.

Comment: @Cerike Yes, issue is string to `double`. Sorry if the point was not clear.  Consider a string of decimal digits with the _exact_ representation of the value _exactly_ midpoint between `DBL_MIN` and the next larger `double` (call is `next`).  This string has over 1000 characters with about 300 leading `'0'`.  Consider how one would process that string to form the best `double` answer realizing that a change in the value of the last digit character may shift the best "round-to nearest" `double` answer between `DBL_MIN` and `next`. Processed sequentially, this can take a fair amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make a better fake version of `_sbrk`. I'm not saying this is the best plan, but if it works ...

Give your program a nice global `char heap[4096]` or whatever will fit, and a `char *heap_ptr` and have your `_sbrk` function use it.